# Input element scrollable with text-overflow ellipsis enabled

Tags: html, css

When I add `text-overflow: ellipsis` to an input element, the element is scrollable. When I place my cursor over the element, I can scroll left and right as if the text was full width and not truncated, although there is no text after the `...`. How do I stop this behaviour!?

```css
input {
  width: 180px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<input value="A string that is longer than the input field" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can see the problem you are describing, are you using a specific browser? or scrolling it in an unusual way? (The only ways I can find to scroll it will switch to showing all of the text)

Comment: Do you have a screen on the issue? I can't see it with this particular example

Comment: Hmm, actually, I can replicate it using dev tools to emulate a touch device, but that might be an emulation issue. Are you using gestures to scroll?

Comment: I guess you can add disabled attribute to input to disable this behavior (and input itself).
Not sure if it is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: I am using a Macbook with trackpad gestures to scroll. Disabling the input has no effect on this behaviour.

Comment: Having the same issue. One way to disable that is set the `pointer-events` to `none`. But it also has side-effects.